# Trim spaces between value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
LinkButton section = (LinkButton)gridcheck.Rows[i].FindControl("lbSection");

if (section == sender)
  Response.Redirect(section.Text + ".aspx");
```

Lets say I have an "AirPlane.aspx" page and the database table I am calling is named "Air Plane".  I tried to use this to trim the space between the "r" and "P" but it does not work

```
Convert.ToString(section).Replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're trying to convert the entire object to a string. Instead, you should be able to use the text field and perform a replace directly against it.

```
Response.Redirect(section.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".aspx");
```